# Angular2 *ngIf does not work correctly

Tags: html, angular, loops, if-statement, angular-ng-if

In my code im using *ngIf which should only show one of the two at any times. But the problem is that it only shows the second one , even though the second one should not be shown at some points. Im using a for loop to show all elements, but as you can see in the picture, only the second one is shown even though the second one its value is -1. Thank you for helping!

Code:

```
<ng-template let-internship="rowData" pTemplate="body" *ngIf="favorite?.FavoritesIds.indexOf(internship?.InternshipId) === -1;"><!--TODO BRIAN ngif-->
  <a class="btn btn-default" [routerLink]="['/student/stageopdrachten', internship.InternshipId, false]"><!--Not shown TODO-->
    <i class="glyphicon"></i>Meer
  </a>
</ng-template>
<ng-template let-internship="rowData" pTemplate="body" *ngIf="favorite?.FavoritesIds.indexOf(internship?.InternshipId) !== -1;"><!--TODO BRIAN ngif-->
  <a class="btn btn-default" [routerLink]="['/student/stageopdrachten', internship.InternshipId, true]"><!--always shown-->
    <i class="glyphicon"></i>Meer{{favorite?.FavoritesIds.indexOf(internship?.InternshipId)}}
  </a>
</ng-template>
```

Image: 
[image: Image which shows the state]

Comment: Plunker would be helpful

Comment: Maybe it's the types case and you should replace === and !== with == and != ?

Comment: Changing it to == and != did not do anyting sadly @mankers

Comment: I would love to but I have never used plunker before, but you can see the variables. The FavoritesIds is a number array.@yurzui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `div` instead of ng-template. You cannot use the syntactic sugar * with ng-template.

### [Structural Directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#asterisk)

> The asterisk is "syntactic sugar" for something a bit more
>   complicated. Internally, Angular desugars it in two stages. First, it
>   translates the ***ngIf**="..." into a template attribute, template="ngIf
>   ...",  like this.

```
<div template="ngIf hero">{{hero.name}}</div>
```

> Then it translates the template attribute into a 
>   element, wrapped around the host element, like this.

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="hero">
  <div>{{hero.name}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: You can also use `<ng-container>` instead of `<ng-template>`, then you can use the more convenient `*ngFor` syntax.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer would you be able to provide any additional information as to "why" it doesn't work correctly?

Comment: `<div *ngIf="..."></div>` is the same as `<ng-template [ngIf]="..."><div></div></ng-template>`. So if you use the `*xxx` syntax an `<ng-template>` element is created implicitly. With `<ng-template *ngIf="...">` you would create an `<ng-template [ngIf]="..."><ng-template></ng-template></ng-template>` and nothing would be displayed because the inner template would never be stamped to the DOM. Is this what you mean with "it"?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean, but why would the inner template never be included in the DOM? Surely if the condition for `<ng-template *ngIf="...">` is true, it should not matter how many layers of ng-template are nested within. E.G this would still display would it not? `<ng-template><ng-template>hello</ng-template></ng-template` Is there something I'm missing about the nature of `ng-template` ?

Comment: A `<ng-template>` by itself doesn't display anything, it's just a container. The `NgIf` directive with `<ng-template [ngIf]="..."><ng-template>xxx</ng-template></ng-template>` would create an `<ng-template></ng-template>` when the NgIf expression becomes truthy, but Angular doesn't actually add `<ng-template>` to the DOM (it handles it only internally in JavaScript). Therefore some other component or directive would need to fetch this `<ng-template>` and stamp `xxx` to the DOM, but there is none, because `NgIf` only cares about the `<ng-template>` where it's applied to.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

Like @Daniel Cooke said, I should have used a div because the ng templates dont work that well when next to eachother. Rather use divs and only one ng template did it. So the working code:

```
<ng-template let-internship="rowData" pTemplate="body" ><!--TODO BRIAN ngif -->
          <div *ngIf="favorite?.FavoritesIds.indexOf(internship?.InternshipId) === -1">
            <a class="btn btn-default" [routerLink]="['/student/stageopdrachten', internship.InternshipId, false]"><!--niet bestaat TODO-->
              <i class="glyphicon"></i>Meer
            </a>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="favorite?.FavoritesIds.indexOf(internship?.InternshipId) != -1;">
            <a class="btn btn-default" [routerLink]="['/student/stageopdrachten', internship.InternshipId, true]"><!--wel bestaat-->
              <i class="glyphicon"></i>Meer{{favorite?.FavoritesIds.indexOf(internship?.InternshipId)}}
            </a>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
```

Comment: Use `<ng-container>` instead of `<ng-template>`, then you can use the more convenient `*ngFor` syntax

Comment: Thanks for the advice, ill use it instead in the future @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score -1):

Do a {{favorite?.FavoritesIds.indexOf(internship?.InternshipId) | json}} to see whats in the variable

My tip is to place the if statement in a separate function.

Its possible that === tests on string while its a number.

Comment: The ngIf should work on numbers, I searched it up before I asked it here